# How to get salesforce custom object in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, salesforce, apex

I would like to set up a dev environment using Visual Studio Code. I'm able to do that with the help of Salesforce Extension Pack. I want to fetch all custom objects in the VS Code. How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this goal in the VS Code you can use this ways. Please find below

Org browser Extention => You can import selected components like custom objects.